# view Render/HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django project working on localhost producing a view with :

```
def entry_list(request):
    editedbooks = EditedBook.objects.all()
    treaty = Treaty.objects.all()
    pilcases = PILCase.objects.all()
    journalarts = JournalArt.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'text/test.bib', {'treaty': treaty,'editedbooks': editedbooks,'pilcases': pilcases, 'journalarts': journalarts}, content_type='text/x-bibtex; charset=UTF-8')
```

The view works. I need to push a text file of the view to a publicly available repository such as git. I'm not sure how to modify the existing view function so that it functions as it does now but renders a bib (plain text) file. Could you please advise? Render to localhost and manually push the repository or is it possible to render to a remote location?

Deploying to Heroku I got stuck on migrating the local SQLite database to the remote PostgreSQL database. The localhost environment works. Can `render()` produce a file or do I need to change to `httpresponse()` or can I somehow subclass the existing function?

- Python Python 3.7.2
- Django 1.9
- Running in virtual environment on Mac

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You already do render a plain-text bib file; what do you need it to do that it's not already doing? (And I don't see how Heroku would help.)

Comment: When you say _produce a file_ do you mean write a file to the local (server) filesystem, or trigger a "Save as" dialog in the browser?